# SCP via SSH internals

Tags: ssh, rcp, scp

So I was playing around with SCP and had a few questions. First, for reference, here's a log file of my SCP session:

```
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST (since last: 0.0021, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  62:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:65:78:65:63:01:00:00  b........exec...
00000010  00:1d:73:63:70:20:2d:74:20:2f:68:6f:6d:65:2f:xx  ..scp -t /home/u
00000020  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2f:7a:7a:7a:2f:61:62:63:64     sernam/zzz/abcd

...

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.2607, network: 0.2576s)
00000000  5e:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01:00                    ^.........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0014, network: 0.0002s)
00000000  5e:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:1f:43:30:36:34:34:20:35  ^........C0644 5
00000010  20:2f:68:6f:6d:65:2f:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2f:7a   /home/usernam/z
00000020  7a:7a:2f:61:62:63:64:0a                          zz/abcd.

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0509, network: 0.0483s)
00000000  5e:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:39:01:73:63:70:3a:20:65  ^.......9.scp: e
00000010  72:72:6f:72:3a:20:75:6e:65:78:70:65:63:74:65:64  rror: unexpected
00000020  20:66:69:6c:65:6e:61:6d:65:3a:20:2f:68:6f:6d:65   filename: /home
00000030  2f:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:2f:7a:7a:7a:2f:61:62:63  /usernam/zzz/abc
00000040  64:0a                                            d.
```

1. Is there a way to make scp errors be sent via stderr (SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA) instead of stdout (SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)?
2. Why is the filename specified twice? Once in the initial scp call and once in the "C0644 5 filename" part? Seems like only one should be necessary? (in my testing doing the basename for the second one makes the error go away but it still seems redundant)
3. Why is SCP sending those null byte SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA packets? None of the SCP clients I've looked at create any sort of pty via SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST so why does SCP seem to act as though there is one and why is the SSH server letting it?
4. In that initial "C0644 5 filename" part, after the `scp -t` command was ran, why is the "C" necessary? It's for the permissions but why not just omit the C and have it be a string representation of the octal value for the mode?

(I'm including the rcp tag btw since I figure rcp and scp are supposed to be pretty similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On Linux, at least, scp(1) does send errors to stderr on the initiating side, as confirmed by running various failing commands with ">/dev/null" on the end to redirect normal stdout to /dev/null, and thereby showing only stderr.
2. The first filename occurrence appears to be in the "scp -t ", part of telling the remote SSH what to do. The latter occurrence is in the SCP protocol being communicated through the SSH link.  See the URL mentioned below for more info.
3. This one I'm not sure about - it'd take more digging .
4. The strace(1) output confirms the "C", I'm seeing `write(7, "C0664 16245 xdrvlib.c\n", 22) = 22` here.  The "C" means file copy, other possibilities are "D" and "E" for directory copies, and "T" for times.  For more information see the nice webpage at: `https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works`